# ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2 - display directory list rather than home/index

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I just download ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2, create a new project and run it. But why it displays a directory list rather than default page ? I'm using VS2008 SP1 and ASP.NET MVC 1 installed.

Comment: Which directory is it giving you the listing for?

Comment: Are you running on IIS6 or IIS7?

Comment: I'm on Windows XP and use default VS web server, the directory listing the application root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project and select **properties**.  Under **web** set the **Start Action** to **Specific Page** and then select the desired page.

Comment: Ok, I set the Start URL to http://localhost:[PORT]/home/ and it works. It just weird that this happen only to this release. ASP.NET MVC 1 working just fine :)

Comment: It depends on what file you have open for editing at the time that you did not have a particular startup action set.

Answer (score 1):

You need set your default start page inside your visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened to me when developping localy with the IIS emulator with Visual Studio 2008 Web Dev. edition. The fix is to simply stop the ASP.NET Developpement server & restart Visual Studio.

Comment: this issue randomly happened to me today on an old app, and this fixed it!! THANKS :-)

Answer (score 0):

go to your project property, select Web and set the specific page to your controller or controller/specific action if you don't want to go to index by default.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem when you install SQL Server 2008 after VS 2010, some corruptions to .NET framework happens... anyway, here you can find how to fix it:

http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/fix-bad-module-managedpipelinehandler-in-iis7

Comment: please post details, not just links. When that link breaks your answer will help no one

Answer (score 0):

The post is very old but stil I face this issue.

I also downloaded the MVC 2 project template for VS 2008 and tried running the default MVC 2 web application.
It displayed the directory listing instead of the home page.

The same default MVC2 project in VS2010 displays the home page when runs in 2010.

The routing is exactly the same in both the projects.

The only workarund I found is to set the start action to the specific page.
Go to Project -->  Properties --> select tab 'Web' from right hand side tabs.
Select radio buton 'Specific Page' under 'Start Action' and set it to the default url.

Like for default web site if you set it to Home/Index, it displays the home page while running.