# Publish ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor) app onto remote server running Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

I have built an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application (with exlusively Razor/cshtml pages) that runs fine on my local machine with IIS Express. Now I'm trying to publish it to a remote server that is running Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6 and has just been upgraded to .NET Framework 4.0.

I was able to successfully publish all the files to the proper directory on the remote server using Visual Studio 2010's Publish dialog (Publish method: FTP), and I've followed the instructions for including all the DLLs needed to run ASP.NET MVC on a machine that doesn't have it installed, but now I'm pretty much stuck.

The first issue is that I don't have access to the remote server's IIS. I *may* be able to get the hosting company to add a virtual directory or change a setting, but I'm not sure they know what they're doing, and at the moment, I wouldn't know what to tell them anyway.

The second issue is that I need my web app to live *inside* an existing site (the web app is basically a protected members area of the main website). So, pretend the main site is http://www.foobar.com. I'd like my web app to be accessed by entering the URL http://www.foobar.com/members.

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to publish my web app without access to the remote server's IIS?
2. If not, what exactly do I need to tell the hosting company to add or change in IIS?
3. Do the settings under the Web tab of project properties affect publishing or just local debugging? At the moment, I have it set to use IIS Express, and the Project URL is "http://localhost:7373/". Do I need to change these?
4. Given that the remote server is running Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6.0, is it possible to use Web Deploy or am I limited to FTP?
5. If I can use Web Deploy, what do I put for the Service URL? All I have right now is a URL in the format of ftp://www.foobar.com/www and a username and password.
6. If I need to use FTP, what steps do I need to take to get the app working once the necessary files have been uploaded to ftp://www.foobar.com/www/members? I'm not worried about database, security certificates, registry, GAC, etc., I just want to know the steps necessary to get the home page of my web app to come up when I put http://www.foobar.com/members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx) article by Scott Hanselman?
In addition to that article, please read the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186695/mvc3-rc-deploy-on-iis6-giving-403-forbidden-error/4603576#4603576) on StackOverflow on pretty much the same environment as yourself.

**Edit**

Your first step should be to get the hosting company to set up the virtual directory with the following parameters (IIS 6):

- ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319 (or later)
- Local Path: [root ftp path for main website]\Members
- [ ] Script source access (unchecked)
- [x] Read (checked)
- [ ] Write (unchecked)
- [ ] Directory browsing (unchecked)
- [x] Log Visits (checked)
- [x] Index this resource (checked)
- Application Name: Members
- Execute Permissions: Scripts only
- Application Pool: ASP.NET 2.0

Comment: Yes. I think I have that aspect of things working fine. I'm stuck on the actual publish part and what to do about IIS.

Comment: What are you getting now? You said you deployed it and didn't really tell us what you are experiencing.

The only problem that I see might be the url rewriting which you can solve by looking at this (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) article. Basically specifying an extension in your routes.

Comment: Well, if I enter the "http://www.foobar.com/members" (this is a fake URL for the sake of explanation), I get Directory Listing Denied. (But I think this makes sense because I haven't set up a virtual directory in IIS because I don't have access to IIS and I can't figure out how to get web deploy to work).

Comment: They will need to setup a virtual directory for you. If you don't have access to a control panel of sorts, you will have to get it created. Let's take it from there then, unless someone else has a better detailed description of their experiences.

Comment: So, are you saying I can't do Web Deploy?

Comment: You can, but the virtual directory needs to be setup, any hosting provider should be able to do this for you.

Comment: Okay, I just got off the phone with them. They are setting it up now. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: PieterG, no luck. They created the virtual directory, but if I go to `http://www.foobar.com/members`, I get a Directory listing instead of the home page of my web app. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537757/asp-net-mvc-2-preview-2-display-directory-list-rather-than-home-index

Comment: Hmm...that didn't do it. I set the Specific Page to "Views/Home/Index.cshtml", but it's still showing the directory listing. Do I need to set the Start URL instead?

Comment: Wait a second...when I do FTP publish, should it be uploading just the bin folder? It seems to be uploading a level up from that, so App_Data, bin, Content, Global.asax, Scripts, Views, Web.config are all getting uploaded to the Members directory. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I have another article that was just posted by Phill Haack. It's bin deploying an asp.net mvc 3 site. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx. Probably unrelated but to answer your question. You are uploading it to the correct location.

Comment: @DanM - i think that @PieterG is on the right track wrt the virtual folder. The other part I think that will do the trick is to ensure that your newly created 'virtual directory' is actually setup as an application with its own application pool. This should give you a start, but If im not mistaken the Default Web Site has specific quirks - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/11/22/virtual-application-vs-virtual-directory.aspx

Comment: Well, it turns out there was a miscommunication at the hosting compnay, and the machine the site was on never was upgraded to ASP.NET 4.0. As of this morning, they finally got that done, and now the site is coming up! I'm still having some problems, but I think the answer to my question was simply to set up a virtual directory, so I'll mark this as the answer. Pieter, in case someone else comes across this question, I'm updating your answer with the key information from this long comment thread. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am glad that you finally sorted it out Dan! :) Happy Razoring ;)